# Consecutive IDs in a navigation property List

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to make a discussion forum in ASP.NET MVC 5 (mostly as a test as I'm pretty new to C#/MVC/any coding).

I have two classes, Discussion and Message.

```
public class Discussion
{
    public int DiscussionID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Discussion Title")]
    public string DiscussionTitle { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    //ForumUser UserCreatedThread { get; set; }

    [Required]
    DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Message
{
    public int MessageID { get; set; }

    public int MessageNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Message Content")]

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText), AllowHtml]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime MessageTime { get; set; }

    public virtual int DiscussionID { get; set; }
}
```

Discussion has a list of Messages which I would like the MessageID, or another property to be ordered 1,2,3,etc for each list. Currently if more than one discussion is created the MessageID can be 1,4,5,8,etc.

I started using a static method in the GetMessage() and GetDiscussion() methods to fix the IDs as the messages were returned to the controller by ordering the threads by the MessageID then iterating over them to change the values to 1,2,3,etc.

Now I've changed that to add a MessageNumber property, save the message to the database when a new message is created (using EF6), retrieve the message, get the count of messages, update MessageNumber to the count and save the changes.

The latter works but I assume could cause problems if a new message is created between saving the message then retrieving the count. Two messages would have the same MessageNumber.

Is there a better way to do this or a should I use a different way to access the messages that doesn't need the ID?

Comment: Why is it that you want the IDs to be consecutive?

Comment: I was basing it on a design that has the message number at the top of each message when viewing the discussion. And referencing a single message would then use the same number.

Answer (score 0):

The id is just the key for the table; it's not really intended to be part of the UI, even though you commonly see ids floating around in URLs across the web. It's far better to expose and use something like a slug for user-facing scenarios.

Regardless, though, what you're trying to do is really not possible. The id is typically set as an identity column, and is auto-incremented for each row in the table. Even if you don't rely on auto-increment and set it manually, you still need to ensure a unique value for each one (i.e., you can't repeat id 1 for multiple rows. The only way around this would be to create a composite key utilizing a manually set id and something like the foreign key to the Discussions table, but *that's really, really, not a good thing to do*. Please, don't do that. Not only would any good DBA smack you for using a foreign key as part of a composite key for another table, but then you have a *ton* manual work to do each time you want to save a new message.

My best advice is to just not worry about the id. If you want a consecutive number, you can create another property much like the `MessageNumber` property you have already and put anything you want in that as long as it's not a key or index for the table. That means you can't (or at least shouldn't) actually *retrieve* anything using that field. You would still need to lookup by the actual row id, or something like a slug, as mentioned earlier.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. I'm not really happy with the way things are working at the moment (they are working fine but overly complicated behind the scenes) so I might change the way things work. I'll have a look at the slug, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to do what you want to do, but if your implementation of Messages is a List, then you can use an index and add one to it. An indexes are by nature consecutive numbers. You would do that something like this:

```
int index = Messages.FindIndex(message => message.MessageID = theID);
```

If you want something a little more flexible:

```
Messages.Select((m, index) => new { index, Message = m })
        .Single(message => message.MessageID == theID);
```

Comment: Like I said in the comment to my first post, the design is based off a different forum that where threads/posts have IDs, listed at the top of each message. For example 123.1, 123.2, etc. And post 2 references post 1 if it was a reply to it. All different to human readable URLs that seem to be in use now. And thanks, I'll look at FindIndex for now before deciding what better way to display my messages.

Comment: Well then, I guess you should create another property in your Message class. But I would think about whether you want to keep it as a number in consecutive order.

Comment: Is it ok to retrieve messages from the database separately? Apart from the first message created in a discussion the rest of the messages are added retrieved by doing db.Mesaages.Where(x=>x.DiscussionID) to avoid loading the whole list of messages when the discussion is retrieved with the message list. So it almost seems pointless having Discussion with the list.

Comment: And FindIndex would only work if the whole list is retrieved with the discussion which would be inefficient when only one or a short set of messages is required.

Comment: Actually the List syncs the DiscussionID between the discussion and first message when a discussion is created. Knew I found it useful for something.

Comment: Correct. Where my code says Messages, I was referring to the member of  the Discussion class. I assumed it would only contain the messages for that Discussion. I figured you would want the messages for just that discussion to be indexed.